# Unable to set pan and zoom without a visual gap

Tags: svgpanzoom

Using svg-pan-zoom utility, I want to register the zoom and pan values every time is changes (using `onPan()` and `onZoom()`) and use these saved values to pan and zoom my SVG to the same position (using `pan()` and `zoom()`).

I works fine if the zoom level is not changed, however, if zoom level is changed, I have a gap between the wanted position of the svg and the real one.

You can see this problem in [that fiddle](https://codepen.io/Rmi69/pen/rNajEJy): first, zoom in, then press the Pan button.
I would like my svg to keep its current location.

I have read other posts on stackoverflow about similar situations (I guess I should use data from `getSizes()`) but I'm still unable to make it work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the solution, which is quite obvious.
While zooming, I need to apply a zoom factor to the saved pan.

```
onZoom: function(zoom) {
  ratio = zoom/currentZoom;
  currentZoom = zoom;
  currentPan = {
    x: currentPan.x*ratio,
    y: currentPan.y*ratio
  }
}
```

See full code [here](https://codepen.io/Rmi69/pen/XWJMNob)